# Extracting specific JSON values in python

Tags: python, json

JSON return from spotify api. Example:

```json
{
    "tracks": {
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Stero+Hearts&type=track&offset=0&limit=1",
        "items": [
            {
                "album": {
                    "album_type": "album",
                    "artists": [
                        {
                            "external_urls": {
                                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4IJczjB0fJ04gs4uvP0Fli"
                            },
                            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4IJczjB0fJ04gs4uvP0Fli",
                            "id": "4IJczjB0fJ04gs4uvP0Fli",
                            "name": "Gym Class Heroes",
                            "type": "artist",
                            "uri": "spotify:artist:4IJczjB0fJ04gs4uvP0Fli"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Broken Code

```py
import requests, json


spotifytrack = input("Name of Song?\\n")
link = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + spotifytrack + "&type=track&limit=1"
token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
header = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
}
auth_response = requests.get(link, headers=header)
pretty_response = json.dumps(auth_response.json(), indent=4)
data_by_user = {}


for d in auth_response:
    data_by_user[d["artist"]] = d
    print(data_by_user["uri"])


"""
def find_track_from_json(auth_response, artist):
    return [p for p in auth_response if p["artist"] == artist][0]["uri"]


urii = find_track_from_json(auth_response, "uri")
print(urii)
x = load.json(auth_response.json())
print("Here is the data whic we have imported\n")
print(pretty_response)
print(x["name"])
print(x["uri"])
print(x["spotify"])
"""
```

Errors noticed:

```
  File "spotify.py", line 19, in <module>
    data_by_user[d["artist"]] = d
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The aim is to convert word search to link in a cli application.

I tried `load.json` which i saw in some website and also tried `def`.

I expected the program to find out the artist name and uri from the json and print it in the cli interface.

Comment: you should reformat your python code (add indent) so that it is able to run otherwise it is very hard to help you.

Comment: Where do these backslashes come from?

Comment: I did my best to update the format while preserving the code with its issues. If this alters your question, feel free to revert it. But for others that come in the future, it is imperative that we don't have incorrect formatting with many extra control characters.

Comment: @KlausD. I believe those backslashes came when i try to edit the code the second time I didn't have it on the original copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result from requests.get() is a [requests.Response](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object. As far as I can see you want to iterate over the response body which is JSON. The requests.Response object has a .json() method which returns a dict from the response JSON.

Looking at the response you would probably want to iterate over `resp_json['tracks']['items']` which is a list.

So to summarize your code should look something like this:

```
auth_response = requests.get(link, headers=header)
items = auth_response.json()['tracks']['items']
for d in items:
    print(d)
```

Comment: Heyy @Georgi Goranov Thank you sm it worked. I do have a doubt in the response from the result from request.get() I wanted 2 fields only. The code prints a lot of unnecessary stuff is there a way to overcome this issue. 

[Link to request.get()](https://textuploader.com/t102z)

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the encoded json string:

```
auth_response = requests.get(link, headers=header)
for d in auth_response:
```

Python is complaining that you aren't providing a numerical index, which is correct as `auth_response` is just a string!

You should call [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to decode the string, and then you can iterate over it.

```
auth_response = requests.get(link, headers=header)
decoded_auth_response = json.loads(auth_response)
data_by_user = {}
for d in decoded_auth_response:
    data_by_user[d["artist"]] = d
```

As you haven't provided the full json output from the API call I'm not sure what data is actually in `decoded_auth_response`, and you haven't described what your expected output would look like, so you may need to do some more work to find the correct data in each iteration.

Comment: I tried to call json.loads but i had this issue before `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response`.

Comment: I expected it to select a certain few values from this huge json response from requests.get.
[link to API response json] (https://textuploader.com/t102z). I wanted few fields such as uri and name to be printed.